# Bash Alias - Precedence/Shadowing (/hiding/failing)

Tags: bash

I have some aliases setup (in this order) in .bashrc:

```
alias ls="lsc"
alias lsc='ls -Flatr --color=always'
alias lscR='ls -FlatrR --color=always'
```

Confirming them with `alias` after sourcing:

```
alias ls='lsc'
alias lsc='ls -Flatr --color=always'
alias lscR='ls -FlatrR --color=always'
```

I can run the newly aliased `ls` just fine, and it chains through to the lsc alias, and then executes the command associated with the lsc alias. I can also run `lscR` and it operates as expected.

If I try to run `lsc` itself though, I get:

```
$ lsc
lsc: command not found
```

Any idea why the shell seems to be shadowing/hiding the lsc alias in this scenario?
(I realise it's pointless to run 'lsc' when I can just run 'ls' to get the same result here, but I'm trying to understand the shells behaviour in this scenario).

**EDIT: Workarounds below for the (bash) shell behaviour provided in the question answers.**

Some really helpful answers have been provided to the original question. In order to short-circuit the expansion behaviour that is explained in the answers, there seems to be at least two ways of preventing a second alias, from trying to expand a command that you have already aliased. For example, if you have `alias cmd='cmd --stuff'` which is overriding a native command called `cmd`, you can prevent the 'cmd' alias from being used in place of the native `cmd` within other aliases, by:

(thanks to wjandrea's comment for this first approach)

1. prefixing `cmd` with 'command' in the other alias e.g. `alias other-cmd-alias='command cmd --other-stuff'`

or,

2. Similarly, you can escape aliases (as you can also do on the command line), within other aliases by prefixing with a backslash '', e.g. `alias other-cmd-alias='\cmd --other-stuff'`.

Comment: Workaround: use`command` in `alias lsc='command ls ...'`

Comment: The other thing I discovered one can do, is to escape commands in an alias, the same as one might do to override an alias on the command line. For instance if you `alias ls='ls some-other-alias'`, but want to use 'ls' the command in it's raw form in a different alias, you can use `alias ls2='\ls --funky-other-alias'` and it seems to prevent the shell from expanding 'ls' within the ls2 alias, and just executes plain old 'ls'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bash does allow aliases to contain aliases but it has built-in protections against infinite loops.  In your case, when you type `lsc`, bash first expands the alias to:

```
ls -Flatr --color=always
```

Since `ls` is also an alias, bash expands it to:

```
lsc -Flatr --color=always
```

`lsc` is an alias but, quite sensibly, bash refuses to expand it a **second time**.  If there was a program named `lsc`, bash would run it.  But, there is not and that is why you get `command not found`.

#### Addendum

It is different when `lscR` runs.  `lscR` expands to:

```
ls -FlatrR --color=always
```

Since `ls` is an alias, this expands to:

```
lsc -FlatrR --color=always
```

Since `lsc` is an alias, this expands to:

```
ls -Flatr --color=always -FlatrR --color=always
```

Since `ls` has already been expanded once, bash refuses to expand it **a second time**.  Since a real command called `ls` exists, it is run.

#### History

As noted by [Schily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/120884/schily) in the comments, bash borrowed the concept of not expanding an alias a second time from [ksh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh).

#### Aside

Aliases are useful but not very powerful.  If you are tempted to do something complex with an alias, such as argument substitution, don't; use a shell function instead.

Comment: Ah, that is so obvious now you mention it! Somehow in my head I must have been imagining it being processed as a top to bottom flow, so it didn't occur to me that there was a recursive call 'back up' to the ls alias above. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Further question in light of your explanation, how come when I call `lscR` it doesn't expand the ls call in that alias (since there is an `alias ls='lsc'`) and then end up running the lsc alias instead? it definitely runs the command aliased to lscR (verifiable because it uses the recursive ls, not single level ls as used in the ls and lsc aliases)....EDIT: I think the explanation here is tied in with muru's answer below actually.

Comment: @Chris That is because, when running `lscR`, it is `ls`, not `lsc`, that bash refuses to expand the second time.  Since a real command named `ls` exists, bash runs it.  I added a more detailed explanation of this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the shell behaviour John. I also expected `ls` to whinge about receiving multiple sets of arguments as in `ls -Flatr --color=always -FlatrR --color=always`, but it doesn't seem to be concerned and just crunches away (more 
 man'ing from the looks of it...)...so, with curiosity satisfied, I can go back to some slightly more sane alias definitions :-)

Comment: You are correct, but the concept you are describing is not from bash but from ksh.

Comment: @Chris Most command-line utilities (oddities like `rsync` & `find` are exceptions) handle repeated options gracefully.  If two options contradict each other (such as ls' `-U` and `-t` options), the later specified option overrides the one specified first.  This makes aliases work sensibly.

Comment: @schily Thanks for that info.  I added the ksh history to the answer.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re saying about `find` options.  `-mtime -111 -mtime -222` is equivalent to `-mtime -111` (the more restrictive one).  `-mtime -42 -mtime +56` gives you a range (six to eight weeks).  OK, alias chaining could result in `-print -print`, and I’ll admit that the fact that that prints twice is not as elegant as things like `ls -l -l`.

Answer (score 6):

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases):

> The first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases, but a
> word that is identical to an alias being expanded is not expanded a
> second time. This means that one may alias `ls` to "`ls -F`", for
> instance, and Bash does not try to recursively expand the replacement
> text.

In the `ls` alias, `ls` is expanded to `lsc` and then again to `ls -Flatr --color=always`, and there the alias expansion stops, since `ls` was originally being expanded. So, the command runs fine, `ls` now being resolved to an external command.

In the `lsc` alias, `lsc` is expanded to `ls -Flatr --color=always`, and then `ls` is now expanded to `lsc` and *there* the alias expansion stops, since `lsc` was originally being expanded. So, the command fails, since bash doesn't know of any other `lsc`.

Comment: Thanks muru, this was also a great answer that I could just have easily accepted as the solution. Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer and John1024 got in first, but thanks for taking the time to provide this, it was helpful.